# Bootstrap popover doesn't appear the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with bootstrap popover, in particular it appear only the second time that I hover the mouse on it. The first time nothing is displayed, I don't understand why. This is my code:

```
 <div id="popover-content" class='popup' rel='popover'>hover me</div>
```

this is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').on('mouseover', '.popup', function()
    {
     console.log("sdsdsds");

     $('body').popover({
            placement: 'bottom',
            container: 'body',
            html: true,
            selector: '[rel="popover"]',
            trigger: 'hover focus',
            title:  'test',
            content: 'foo' 
     });
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hbzmj8n/10/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the `$('body').on('mouseover', '.popup', function()` and it will work.

Updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1hbzmj8n/13/).

If you want to bind the `mouseover` you can chain it to the `popover` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    selector: '[rel="popover"]',
    trigger: 'hover focus',
    title: 'test',
    content: 'foo'
  }).on('mouseover', '.popup', function() {
    console.log('test')
  });

});
```

Comment: but I need to fire it when the mouse is on specific item.. the control actually in jsfiddle is only a demo, so I guess the problem is on the jquery event?

Comment: @AgainMe, nice. I'm glad I could help.